# What happens when a request is sent to an invalid domain name in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library. When I try to send a request to invalid domain name, my app crashes, so I want to know what happens in the background and how can I solve this issue ?
A demo code will help me.

```
final RequestQueue reQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final String url="http://www.googkjle.com";  // invalid domain name
    checkbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            StringRequest request=new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,
                    url, 
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(
                        String response) {


                        showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "INTERNET ACCESS", "You have internet access"+response.substring(0,50));

                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(
                        VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int a=error.networkResponse.statusCode;
                    showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Ohh. NO INTERNET ACCESS", "You do not have internet access");

                    System.out.println("status code : "+a);
                }
            });

                reQueue.add(request);

        }
    });



}



public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title,String message) {

    AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

**LogCat:**

```
08-27 00:37:42.735: D/gralloc_goldfish(2637): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-27 00:37:46.445: D/AndroidRuntime(2637): Shutting down VM
08-27 00:37:46.445: W/dalvikvm(2637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a03ba8)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): Process: com.exampfle.real, PID: 2637
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.exampfle.real.MainActivity$1$2.onErrorResponse(MainActivity.java:78)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:563)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:101)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-27 00:37:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(2637):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: pls show your logcat

Comment: I have not found any problem with your code. How do you use volley library, jar file or `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'` in `build.gradle`? If put logging at onErrorReponse, normally will get the message `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.googkjle.com": No address associated with hostname`

Comment: I am using volley as a jar file

Comment: Is the above your the code that leads to the error in your logcat? It seems as if you are causing the NPE in your onResponse (that has nohting in it).

Comment: So, try using `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'`

Comment: what is line MainActivity.java:78

Comment: handle code well in onErrorResponse() you are getting a NPE over there

Comment: Maybe error or error.netwrokRespond is null

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread the line number... fixing the Answer

If the line 78 on your MainClass is:

`int a=error.networkResponse.statusCode;`

Then networkResponse is likely null, and is causing the NPE - Null Pointer Exception

You can fix this by:

```
try{
   int a=error.networkResponse.statusCode;
} catch (NullPointerException e){
   // Dont know... perhaps just put a Toast to show... or
   int a=-1;
}
```